# To convert a particular format to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I am getting a date component from web service as @"2014-01-08T00:00:00.000Z". I need to convert it into a date only providing me with year , month and date. Please help

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns

Comment: This question has been asked more than 10000 times, next time try using google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to get the Current Date

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFor=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *currentDateString = @"2014-01-08T21:21:22.737+05:30";

[dateFor setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];        
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFor dateFromString:currentDateString];

NSLog(@"CurrentDate:%@", currentDate);
```

Comment: This isn't what's been asked. He said `providing me with year , month and date.`

Comment: @Desdenova but this provides date in year, month and date.

Comment: Sure but you need to format it one more time to strip the time out of it.

Comment: @Desdenova i think it is enough for user to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the output year- month -date in like that format then use below code. Also you need to convert the format into specified below format:-

```
NSString *currentDateString = @"2014-01-08T00:00:00.000Z";
self.dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *currentDate = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    currentDateString=[self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"CurrentDate:%@", currentDateString);
```

**Output:-**

```
CurrentDate:2014-01-08
```

Comment: @Hussan Shabbir i edited the answer.your answer perfect no need of editing sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the date from string again change the format of dateformatter and then get the string using formatter.

```
NSString *currentDateString = @"2014-01-08T21:21:22.737+05:30";

NSDateFormatter *dateFor=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFor setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];        
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFor dateFromString:currentDateString];
[dateFor setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];

// above format will show date as Dec 31, 2013 something like this
// can use other format as well like. [dateFor setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]

NSString *dateString =  [dateFor stringFromDate:currentDate];
```