# NSString to NSDate for yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.+05:30 format

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My date string that I am getting is 1991-01-26T00:00:00+05:30 of this format from web service. How do i confer it to NSDate?

I tried:

```
    NSString *p=@"1991-01-26T00:00:00+05:30";

    NSDateFormatter *dateformat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];

    NSDate *datefor=[dateformat dateFromString:p];

    [dateformat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"];

    NSString *dateStr=[dateformat stringFromDate:datefor];


    NSDate *datetype=[dateformat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

It returns nil. Any thoughts?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033892/converting-date-of-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sss

Comment: Do you want to extract "1991-01-26" from your string?

Comment: Not only has this question been asked many many times, it has also been asked at least once today. Please learn to do even a minimal about of research and put some effort into your work

Comment: Just change date format with this  [dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssSSSZZZZ"];

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994688/to-convert-a-particular-format-to-nsdate/20995101#20995101

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you have used the wrong format. Use

```
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```

Because you don't have the millisecond so you should not add the `SSS`.

Comment: it will give value with SSSZZZ but there is need to remove only "." After HH:mm:ss

Comment: @Maul, Oh, thank you for tips. But I suggest to remove that to improve readability and understandability.